# Programmatically change the attributes of desktop icons

Tags: scripting, desktop, cinnamon

Whenever I happen to add / remove an icon from my (Cinnamon) desktop, the others either get

- shuffled seemingly at random, from being sorted by name or
- resized, or at least the new icons will be larger than the other icons (the default size)

This is quite annoying, when I expect the icons to be in an arrangement one minute but the next, they've gone awry.

Certainly, rearranging my desktop icons is something I can do when I'm bored out of my mind, but since I don't spend much time looking at my desktop, I wish I could automate this.

Is there some way to script or automate programmatically the alteration of attributes of desktop icons? (in Cinnamon, preferably.)

Comment: Don't know Cinnamon, but does it have any option to lock the icons on your desktop (like KDE does)? That would probably fix it, if it exists. I get really annoyed when something scrambles my icons which I have carefully placed just where I want them! Is there a way to put new device icons in a folder (or somewhere else) instead of directly on the desktop? That would fix it too.

Comment: Unfortunately, Cinnamon is far from KDE and doesn't have the ability to do that. I like KDE but it's almost *too* configurable to use regularly.

Comment: See if this is helpful. http://askubuntu.com/a/573359/334636

Comment: @cdosborn Post that as an answer (with more than a link) and I'll accept it -- that's pretty much exactly what I'm after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gvfs-set-attribute ~/Desktop/fileOrFolder metadata::nemo-icon-position 300,300
```

If you use `nautilus`, substitute `nautilus` for `nemo` in the above command.

Press `<F5>` to refresh your desktop.

Here is a nautilus [script](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718034512/http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Happy+Desktop+-+Organize,+Save,+Restore?content=173843) that may be helpful in saving/restoring your icon positions.

Comment: Now I'm looking for a way to programatically refresh my desktop.

Comment: @TrevorHickey This works for me, to refresh the desktop programmatically: `xfdesktop --reload`

Comment: Your script link is broken :( I was hoping it could help me with this script I need to develop: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146175/desktop-icons-just-dropped-down-left-screen-into-never-never-land

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Check now. If you havn't used it before, lookup the wayback machine.

Comment: @cdosborn Oh your link should have said "Happy Desktop" and then I wouldn't have clicked on it (it takes like 5 to 10 seconds to load?). Anyway I downloaded a version from git a few hours ago and it didn't work very well for me. I'm coding my own version to shift icons between three monitors. Upvoted for your help though :)